# How to find $z$ with $|\sin z | \le 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find all $z \in \mathbb C$ such that $|\sin z |\le 1$.

What I did so far:

Clearly, for all real $z$ this is satisfied.

Next I tried to rewrite it like this:

$$ |\sin z |^2 =  |\sin x + iy |^2= \sin^2 x \cosh^2 y + \cos^2 x \sinh^2 y $$

but this doesn't seem to help. I can bound it by $\cosh^2 y + \sinh^2 y $ but that is not useful.

Now my question is:

> How can I find all $z$ such that $|\sin z | \le 1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use that $\cos^2 x = 1-\sin^2 x$ and $\cosh^2 y-\sinh^2 y=1$, you get:

$$|\sin z|^2 = \sin^2 x\cosh^2 y +(1-\sin^2 x)\sinh^2 y = \sin^2 x + \sinh^2 y$$

So you need:

$$\sinh^2 y \leq 1-\sin^2 x =\cos^2 x$$

Comment: How $\sin z$ is bounded ?? If bounded then it is constant...

Comment: He didn't ask to prove $\sin z$ was bounded, he asked *for what* $z$ is $|\sin z|<1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @ThomasAndrews. Is this where it ends or does there exist a way to simplify $\sinh^2 y \le \cos^2 x$ into something only involving $x$ and $y$ or some other expression which would make it clear what the set looks like when drawn in $\mathbb C$?

Comment: You can solve that inequality in terms of $y$ but it is sort of ugly.